# Replace a file content with environment values - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline, I load the environment properties from a file using plugin. With this I would like to replace a file content with the environment variables loaded or available.

Example:
Property loaded from the file that contains below values

```
property1=value1
property2=value2
```

File content to be replace with the above variables

```
properties: 
  property1: $property1
  property2: $property2
```

The expected output

```
properties: 
  property1: value1
  property2: value2
```

I tried few plugins but I find them read the text and write to a file, but I need to read the file and write to a new file with replaced variables.

Comment: This is not really a use case for Jenkins Pipeline. Other tools exist for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this effective for my problem after having tried multiple approaches.

After setting or loading the properties from file

```
eval "echo \"$(<my-template.yaml)\"" > my-config.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple script containing `sed` command? Creating new file, shouldn't be a big deal.

Take a look for one of these examples:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/
- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

This should fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) step and generate content dynamically.

1. Generate content dynamically in loop using *evaluate("$property")* method for values
2. Pass content to **writeFile** step.